# Creating java.util.map.Entry instance to help unit testing

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermockito

In my code, I have a `for` loop like,

```
for( final Entry<Object, Object> entry : fileTypeProperties.entrySet()) {
    saveFileTypeToCompany(registeredCompany,
             entry.getKey().toString(), 
             entry.getValue().toString());
}
```

So, while unit testing, how to create an instance of `Entry` (i.e., `java.util.map.Entry`) ?

Comment: You usually see it as `Map.Entry`, not just `Entry`, but just convention. `import java.util.Map`, and then change it to `Map.Entry<Object, Object>`.

Answer (score 1):

- You can't create a `Map.Entry` directly as it's an interface. You could create your own class that implements the interface if you want to.
- I can't understand why you'd want to create an entry for the purpose of unit testing. If you are testing `saveFileTypeToCompany` then you pass it the key and value of the entry, not the entry itself. So to unit test you pass test values to the function. If you are testing the code you are showing then you need to populate the map to test it properly. I can't see any scenario in which you need to create an entry directly.
- If you do need to unit test with a `Map.Entry` then use mocking. You can mock the interface and then define what is returned by `getKey` and `getValue`.
- If you are using Java 8 then your code can be simplified to: `fileTypeProperies.forEach((k, v) -> saveFileTypeToCompany(company, k, v));`

Answer (score 0):

What actually you need to do is to load your `fileTypeProperties` with some properties as shown below so that when you call `fileTypeProperties.entrySet()`, it will return the `Entry` objects.

```
Map<Object, Object> fileTypeProperties = new HashMap<>();
// add some dummy property values to fileTypeProperties
```